# Creating program using a single ACCDB database

Tags: c#, ms-access

after many, many hours of research,head scratching, and more research, I have finally decided to come to you guys for help. I am trying to create a program where all the users will point to a single .accdb file. I had everything set up except for when I go to a different computer due to Microsoft.ACE.12.0 requiring each station to have a patch. The issue is in my workplace this will not be practical. Does anyone have any idea of a better way to connect to a database using C# so that I can pull all the needed information.

Comment: What is the "patch" for?  Can you use an earlier version of the Jet driver that doesn't require a patch?

Comment: microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Is the error message I receive on computers that are 64 bit and do not have Access Database Engine installed. I am trying to find a way to make this as simple of an install for the IT department as possible without having to install that on every workstation.

Comment: If installing that driver is a hindrance on client machines I would rebuild the app using a older driver (or a 32-bit driver) that may be standard on those machine (i.e. if they use an older version of office)

Comment: Well I am still extremely new to coding in C# I just got done learning VBA, so I am still trying to learn how to connect to a database let alone grab information from one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand rightly, you have a back-end database which is a single .accdb file but you cannot install patches/updates on the company machines and you need such an update for your app to work.

How are you installing the app? I am guessing it is an .exe running off a network share and you are not running any installer. Can you not get your sysadmins to roll out the necessary prerequisites?

Are you committed to .accdb? If not, perhaps SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/) may work better for you.

Alternatively, if you can get SQL Server (even Express) running somewhere this will serve you better.

Comment: That is correct, I am using a back-end database with a single .accdb file. I am unable to install patches to the computers due to them running unsupported operating systems and being locked down due to corporate mandate.

We are simply copying and pasting a .exe file from a shared server.

I am not commited to .accdb so I shall look into sqlite. With the SQL Server same thing applies due to the corporate mandate, they are not fond of us running independent servers.